# Does tmux have anything like vim's marks?

Tags: tmux

Let's say I'm `tail`ing some logs from a running app and I expect some long output to come soon that I would like to scroll to the top of once it's done. Does tmux have anything that could help me here? I'm thinking something like vim's [marks](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Using_marks), where I could press `ma` to make a mark called `a`, and then press `'a` to jump to that line.

Ideal workflow:

1. `tail -f` some stuff
2. `<prefix> m a` to set a mark called `a`
3. Do something which causes a lot of output to be logged
4. `<prefix> ' a` to jump to where `a` was defined

Comment: Maybe just put a comment like `# mymark` before you start running command 3. and then you can search back to that unique string?

Comment: @mattb That's a good point, but the problem I see is that, in the OP's use-case, the command is already running (`tail -f ...`) -- Presumably it's a log-running `tail` that is always in a particular pane.  The new command in step 3 that causes the log to do something interested is coming in a separate pane, most likely (or even triggered by something entirely external).  It *is* possible to type in the terminal while `tail`ing something, so putting a comment in would work, but only if no additional input comes in while typing.  That might be tough if `tail`'ing a rapidly growing log file.

Comment: Still, I think you should post it as an answer (with a discussion of the caveats, of course) -- I'd upvote it.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds cheers! In the answer I posted I tried to incorporate what you pointed out above.

Answer (score 3):

While Tmux does have a "mark" function, I don't think it will work for your use-case.

In copy-mode, pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> (a.k.a. "X") sets a mark, and <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> will then toggle between the current location and that mark.  The problem is that when you exit copy-mode, the mark is lost.  So you wouldn't be able to run a *subsequent* `tail -f` and get back to that point.

My personal recommendation would be to use a pager for the output that supports (a) following a growing file, and (b) mark/jump functionality.  That can found pretty easily in the `less` command.  Your workflow would be pretty close to what you describe:

1. `less +F` some stuff
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to temporarily exit follow-mode
3. <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to set a mark called "a"
4. <kbd>F</kbd> to restart follow-mode
5. Do something which causes a lot of output to be logged
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to temporarily exit follow-mode (you wouldn't want it scrolling while analyzing your output anyway).
7. <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to jump to your mark
8. <kbd>F</kbd> to restart follow-mode when/if desired

---

*Edit/Update*

If you really want a "mark" and "goto-mark" function, it's *possible*, but *very* hacky, IMHO.  I'm really only posting this because (a) I finally got it to (mostly) work, and (b) I want to get it out of my config, but don't want to lose work.

First, create two separate additional files:

`.tmux-set_mark.tmux`:

```
# Must use "run-shell" since it can run the
# command immediately.  The #() syntax always 
# uses the *previous* results.
# The capture-pane is hackery to get the current 
# line number we are on (starting from the 
# beginning of the history.
run "tmux set-environment TMUX_CUR_LINE $(tmux capture-pane -S - -E - -p | tac | awk 'NF {p=1} p' | wc -l)"

# Store it in a user-option on the current 
# pane.  This allows marks in multiple panes 
# to work.
set-option -F -p @TMUX_MARK "#{TMUX_CUR_LINE}"

display-message "Mark set at line #{@TMUX_MARK}"
```

`.tmux-goto_mark.tmux`:

```
# Must use "run-shell" since it can run 
# the command immediately.  The #() 
# syntax always uses the *previous* 
# results.
run-shell "tmux set-environment TMUX_CUR_LINE $(tmux capture-pane -S - -E - -p | tac | awk 'NF {p=1} p' | wc -l)"

# Set a user option on the pane with 
# the line number we need to goto.
# This is calculated, of course, by 
# subtracting the marked-line-number
# from the current-line-number
set-option -F -p @TMUX_GOTO "#{e|-:#{TMUX_CUR_LINE},#{@TMUX_MARK}}"

copy-mode

# Goto the line.  Again `run-shell` is needed
# here since send-keys can't expand the FORMAT 
# string, but run-shell can.

run-shell 'tmux display-message #{@TMUX_GOTO}'
run-shell 'tmux send-keys -X goto-line #{@TMUX_GOTO}'

# The next two lines are just additional
# hackery to use the built-in TMux marking
# ability so that the marked line is highlighted
# and at the top of the screen
send-keys -X set-mark
send-keys -X jump-to-mark
```

Then, in your `.tmux.conf`, set key-bindings to source these files:

```
unbind x
bind x source-file "$HOME/.tmux-set_mark.tmux"
unbind X
bind X source-file "$HOME/.tmux-goto_mark.tmux"
```

This is horrible, IMHO.  Easier possible methods fail:

- It would be easier if there was a better way to get the current line number you are on in the buffer, but there doesn't seem to be a variable for this.  The closest I could find was `history_size`, but the history doesn't start until you begin scrolling your pane.
- It would be easier if `goto-line` took an absolute line number, instead it is the relative line number from the *bottom* of the buffer in copy-mode, not the top.

There's one additional caveat/bug to this code.  If you do this on the first "page" of a Tmux pane (before you start scrolling), the line that it hightlights will not be the one that you marked.  The alternative is to not use the:

```
send-keys -X set-mark
send-keys -X jump-to-mark
```

But then the `goto-line` will always place the desired mark at the *bottom* of the pane, meaning you will always need to scroll down a pane.

Comment: Also, from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/82068/438036: You can make `less` call Vim (assuming `EDITOR=vim`) on the file it is currently viewing by pressing `v`. `less` will even put your cursor in the correct location within Vim. When you exit Vim, you will find yourself back at `less`. If you made any changes to the file while you were in Vim, they will be reflected in `less`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the comment by @NotTheDr01ds to my comment below the OP, you could append
a unique line to the file you're tailing (if you have write permission and
appending if such a line doesn't interfere with any future use of that log file) before you start the process in step 3
by doing:

```
echo '# mymark' >> file.log && tail -f file.log
```

Or if that's not preferable, and if the file you're tailing isn't growing
rapidly before you start the process in step 3, you could type directly into
the terminal were the output of `tail -f` is shown

```
$ tail -f file.log
 > some line from the log
 > another line from the log
 # mymark!
 > line generated by step3
 > and there will be many more lines generated by step3...
 > .           .           .           .           .           
 > .           .           .           .           .           
 > .           .           .           .           .
```

Then in both cases you could search backwards for the `# mymark` string in
tmux's copy mode (with `?^# mymark`).